# Setting an index based on a value in a row

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a series that consists of three values:

```
Index  Name 
0       CH
1       V2
2       HH
```

The V2 changes frequently with multiple values (SB, FG, UA) so I cannot sort in an alphabetical order.  I need the alternating value at index 0 and CH at index 1 and HH at index 2.  I have tried reindexing and assigning the rows but nothing has worked everytime with a changing V2 value.

Desired output:

```
Index  Name 
0       V2
1       CH
2       HH
```

This is a pretty obvious output from the explanation, but I need CH and HH to always be 1 and 2 respectively no matter what the value at index 0 is.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
# create a diction and assign the sequence in which you likes column sorted
# create a temp column by maping value to string
# sort and drop the temp column

m={'V2':0,'CH':1, 'HH': 2}
df2=(df.assign(seq=df['Size'].map(m)
           .fillna(9))
 .sort_values(['seq', 'Size'])
 .drop(columns='seq'))

df2.index = range(0, len(df2) ) 
df2.reset_index().drop(columns='Index')
```

```
    index   Type    Size
0   0   str     V2
1   1   str     CH
2   2   str     HH
```

Comment: This produces a dataframe that still has CH at index 0 and V2 at 1.

Comment: So I believe this is close, but not quite there yet.  The V2 index needs to be 0.  My desired output is what I would like to happen.  The actual order in the dataframe does not matter I need the index to change to where the CH is index=1 and HH is index=2.

Comment: @JakeP, essentially, V2 at 0, CH at 1 and HH at 2? is that what you were expecting?

Comment: @JakeP, does the revised solution worked?